# React router dont render component then he have parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, slug

**Hello everyone !**

> What is my problem ?

I'm trying to make a product details pages, then I'm using this :

```
 return (
   <Router>
      <div>
         <Header user={this.state.user} setUser={this.setUser} />
      </div>
       <div className="mx-10">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/details/:slug" components={() => <Details />} />
            <Route exact path="/market/search/:categorie" component={DynamicSearchCategory} />
         </Switch>
       </div>
   </Router>
);
```

> This working really well `/market/search/:categorie`

> But if I'm trying to get this pages `/details/:slug`

> I have also try this: `/market/details/:slug`

Nothing will be show if I get product details route but the header appear but the component that I want to render `functional components` or `class components` then nothing will be show

If I do this:

```js
console.log(props)

// or

console.log(this.props) // for class components
```

Nothing will be show in the console no one error.

I don't know if I have miss anything, and I don't understand why the `/market/search/:categorie` work well but not the `/details/:slug`

There is my component who them will receive props:

`class components`

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Details extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <p>Details</p>
        )
    }
}
```

Or in functional components:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function ProductDetails(props) {
    console.log(props.match.params.slug)
    return (
        <>
            <p>Product Details</p>
        </>
    )
}
```

**Edit:**

in my navigator the slug appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Route exact path="/details/:slug" components={() => <Details />} />
```

=>

```
<Route exact path="/details/:slug" component={Details}/>
```

Comment: Hello, I have already try this, the same things... 

Comment: Yeah, second eye is always helpful :)